# Underline text from left to right with loop

Tags: css, css-animations

I've been trying to do the same text underline effect on this website

https://themads.agency/ (links when clicked on hamburger menu)

so far I'm able to do the underline on hover but how do I made it that it repeats?

```
.HvrUnderline{
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
}
.HvrUnderline:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: solid 3px #F16A70;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 100% 50%
}
.HvrUnderline:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: You can't do that with a `transition`...you need a `keyframe` `animation`.

Comment: By repeat, do you mean that you want the underline animation to keep happening over and over until you stop hovering?